# Typescript enforce generic type safety

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I know Typescript is structured typing due to the dynamic nature of Javascript, thus features like generic is not the same as other languages nominal type system. Given that, how do we enforce type safety with generic, specifically array? Suppose I have these classes/types:

```ts
class X {
    fn(env: (number | string)[]) {
        if (typeof env[0] === 'string') {
            console.log('print string and number')
        }
        console.log(env[0] === 0)
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    override fn(env: string[]) {
        console.log(env[0] === '0')
    }
}
```

I used classes, but this holds the same with types.

These expression is understandable, since we explicitly stated the type (similar to `as` if we ignore the fact that both has the same type-less structure):

```ts
const x: X = new Y()
const y: Y = new X()
```

But for example, these expressions are also valid

```ts
const arrX: X[] = [y] // works, as intended Y extends X
const arrY: Y[] = [x] // works, but shouldn't, or at least emit a warning
```

I know that generic like Array in this case get enforced through usage rather than declaration, for example, `arrY.forEach(val => val.fn([0])` will break. I know fully well the limitation of a structured type system, so I'm not asking why, or why shouldn't, I'm asking for a good way to enforce such restriction. I don't mind any workaround. What I want to achieve is essentially some way to convey that: We can use an `Y` as a `X`, but never `X` as an `Y`. I'm also aware that there are more ways to model the association between 2 "types", so I don't need a general solution that can cover all edge cases.

I tried rebrand the generic, looking like this:

```ts
type YEnv = string & {__unused: 'Y' }
class Y /* extends break */ extends X {
    fn (env: YEnv) {...}
}
```

Now since `YEnv` and `number|string` is incompatible, inheritance is broken. Consumers of such API would need to explicitly cast `Y` to `X` to be used in an `Array<X>`. On any nomimal type system we wouldn't need to do this. It's fine with explicitly casting them, but may not be very intuitive.

Comment: This isn't about usage vs declaration. Consider your `const arrY: Y[] = [x]`. The only member is the method `fn` and the parameter types supported by the definition in `X` are a supertype of the parameter types of the method `fn` in `Y`. A method that can happen an array of strings or numbers can certainly handle an array of strings.

Comment: @AluanHaddad you doesn't even understand the problem. This is just a minified example of how Typescript will handle array generic. In practice, A method that expect `an arg with property p1 and p2` is going to blow up when given `an arg with only p1`. That's why you need to clearly tell your user to supply `arrY` with only `Y` instance. That's why nominal type system assert inheritance through one-way casting: `X` **is not** `Y` but `Y` **is** `X`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by normal type systems. Throw away your intuition from nominally typed languages. Also, the hierarchy you have set up violates LSP since `Y` doesn't support the capabilities of `X`. This isn't Java or C# or Kotlin and you should not expect any analogy to hold

Comment: @AluanHaddad it's **nominal**, not **normal**. I didn't stutter even once. Maybe a good 30 seconds of Google would help you. This is Typescript, that's why it sucks. Might as well just say that. See here for an illustrative example why Typescript in a functional programming environment is unsuited: https://shorturl.at/dkpBU

Comment: Take it easy. I did misread nominal and I apologize for that. However, I don't care to debate the merits of the language with you. If you rely on nominal typing you are missing the point of the language and I won't say anything more. Good luck.

Comment: This is the problem with javascript one trick pony coping. Javascript is inherently flawed, breed the next level less flawed child that is Typescript. I don't care if it breaks type guarantees that exists in 90% of programming languages, I care if it can't sufficiently express them. Typescript is very expressive, and oddly enough, Turing complete, so I gave it the benefit of doubt. Btw, the link is just a typescript playground.

Comment: • Where specifically is the “generic” in the question? I see lots of specific types but no obvious generics. • What’s weird here to me is that `Y` is not a proper subtype of `X` because methods are unsafely bivariant; the way I’d want to “fix” this would break your goal further. • But in general, could you just add a property to `Y` that isn’t present in `X`, like a field `y = 1`? (I’m on mobile so I can’t check now, hope to be back at a real computer sometime today)

Comment: @jcalz The generic is in the Array, as `X[]` is `Array<X>`. Rebranding things wouldn't work as well (as I explained in the post). Adding another runtime property to Y would actually work, but that would kill the 0 cost abstraction of types. The JIT may optimize them, but it's always a code smell to depend on the JIT.

In Typescript, `Y` is a subtype of `X`, as well as `X` is a subtype of `Y`. In a structured typing world without extended generic rule, "subtypes" don't actually matter. If it wants to enforce them, it should break the moment I `extends X`. We are in a chicken and the egg game.

Comment: The idea that a single extra field would be an unacceptable loss of performance seems more of a “smell” to me than the opposite assumption, but that’s subjective and you’re welcome to disagree. You can write `declare y: number` and get your 0-cost behavior at runtime.  Does using `declare` meet your needs? If so I’ll write up an answer; if not, why not?

Comment: See prev comment. [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgo7Bw) shows the extra prop (that has 0 runtime impact) as well as the issue with `Y extends X` which I... guess you don't care about, even though I don't understand why (surely `Y extends X` is a more clear problem than `X extends Y` in terms of clearly demonstrable runtime problem. Method bivariance is a necessary evil, not something you should be trying to make happen.) But anyway, does the `declare` thing work as an answer to your question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz yes, it is perfect. Thank you so much. For some explaination why: `X extends Y` means that an `X` is an `Y`, or `X` is usable as `Y` everywhere. Well, in this case, not so much, as we are expressing the maximum type (everything that `X` could work with is `number|string`, and everything that `Y` could work with is `number`). Our setup is more closely resemble the playground link I sent, which is minimum type, requires every that `X` need to work with is `number|string[]`, and doesn't care if there is more, say, the array has an extra `truncate` function.

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance, but I am still confused about why you would want to use `X extends Y` when `Y extends X` is more natural. It's like you put your shoes on your head and then wonder why you're having trouble walking around. I can help you lace the shoes so they stay on your head, but I'm still not getting the point or why you're not just doing it another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, TypeScript's [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) means that type `X` is assignable to type `Y` depending on the *shapes* of the types and not necessarily on their *declarations*.  If one writes `class Y extends X {}` without adding conflicting things into `Y`, then you'll often end up with a situation where `X` is assignable to `Y` despite being a superclass of it.

The issue of assignability is only made more complex and difficult to think about given that [TypeScript isn't perfectly sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), so some of the allowed assignments "should" be rejected, except that the equivalent assignment must be accepted to allow for existing type hierarchies. See [microsoft/TypeScript#9825](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825) for more information. Methods in TypeScript are [bivariant in their parameter types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) unsafely, meaning your `Y` really should not be allowed as a subclass of `X`. But it is, and I'm not going to worry about why you've got it this way, other than to suggest to future readers to beware of such things.

Anyway, the standard approach when you've got `X` assignable to `Y` when you don't want it to be and where you have control over both of the types, is to add something to `Y` to make it incompatible. And the easiest way to do that is to add a member not present in `X`.  A property will do:

```
class Y extends X {
    declare y: number; // <-- add this
    override fn(env: string[]) { }
}
```

Here a `Y` is know thought by TypeScript to contain a numeric `y` property which is not present in `X`.  Since I used [the `declare` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) this doesn't actually change the emitted JavaScript at all. It just says that, according to TypeScript, it's there.  Of course it *isn't* there at runtime, so any code you write should probably stay away from it, and not try to read it or write it. You could make it [`private`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private) to discourage external access, or you could make it `undefined` to better model what's happening, or you could *really* add it to `Y` so that no runtime issues show up. There are all kinds of ways someone might want to proceed, depending on their use cases.

The important part is: when you have accidentally compatible types, modify at least one of them to be incompatible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.3&ssl=12&ssc=33&pln=11&pc=48#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1XQGYDsAUBTTAbgFzTaYCuAtgEa4BO0APtBAC50CWmA5gJQDaAXV6IUacR3SlWATwAOuAPZT8BfgAZB0ALy7oAcjace+kcnEW0wRZgiKQuAHQhF3bPrnHWLdl27QwTAATaAoaelMxSwBfKItrW3snFzdVDS1dbWh1XjjY2KRQSBgATWhcAA9WfCCYeHM0INwiulxoGRIw2joAbmgAen6AoJDA8qq6MGhPRQU6WTjFAnpOJowcVRIjPyEzOPEEuwdnVzxCdJ09fXVIy1RDpJPUwkdKMDlsCp0APmgKx1YigAqnI5gBhSC4bC8XiOABWii40Ny4nySEKNjYfxI8CymFwAHdoCVoRjbN4OsSdKFCXBoQMhitFHR0WSsWA6HRYDihNT+DItINoIoANZgGRs7wcuglEglXlZfgVQWMznM1n-LDYfgARmEfSFAB4ALTG6CsAAWHBg1oCmGg1og5DalsU5G4FoANCxFNAAJL6SihRTeJ2taAEi0ydpu6DGgmBVhmsqVarBOpIIA)